# For two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, if the probability $P (X > Y) > 0.5$, then $E[X] >E[Y]$

Tags: probability, statistics

It was a question posed by our stat teacher in class. He used the example of a two different dice being thrown (where first throw was a 6-sided die $X$ and second was a 4-sided dice $Y$). I wanted to know if there was any formal way of proving this without using specific examples.

Comment: You cannot prove this because it is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three counterexamples.
Consider three dice

- black, with numbers 3,3,4,4,8,8
- white, with numbers 1,1,5,5,9,9
- red, with numbers 2,2,6,6,7,7

Then the probabilities $P(red > white), P(white > black), P(black > red)$ are all $\frac59 > \frac 12$, and yet their expectation is $5$ in each case.

Comment: Oooh thanks man. I am bad at coming up with counters

Answer (score 3):

Does this claim hold for the following?

\begin{equation}
(X,Y) = 
\begin{cases}
(1,0) & \text{with probability 0.51}\\
(0,1000000) & \text{with probability 0.49}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}